# how get sum value in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Am new in Excel VBA. Could someone help me with this:

If `C5` or `D5` is not blank then minus them from cell value of `B5` and get the Sum in cell `E5`,

```
EX: E5= (C5+D5)-B5
```

and the same time the value of `E5` should be reduced from the  value `B5`

```
EX: B5=B5-E5
```

Comment: Ahve you tried entering =(C5+D5)-B5 in cell E5?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample formatting / data as well?

Answer (score 0):

well, if just according to what's in your description it seems like this:

```
Sub summation()

If Cells(5, 3) <> "" Then
If Cells(5, 4) <> "" Then

    Cells(5, 5) = Cells(5, 3) + Cells(5, 4) - Cells(5, 2)
    Cells(5, 2) = Cells(5, 2) - Cells(5, 5)

End If
End If


End Sub
```